# Is it possible to show 403/404 messages on the front page?

Tags: theming

Is it possible to have - instead of a dedicated 403/404 page - just a custom div inserted into the front page? 'Cause when I think of what I'd like to show up at 403404, I want everything that the front page has. So, whatever the front page looks like over time, I would just want it to adopt a 403/404 message div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D6's Error Reporting, if you set your 404 page to 'node', eg the standard front page, you should be able to do something like this in your hook_preprocess_page():

```
function YOURTHEME_OR_MODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  // all your other stuff

  if ($_GET['q']=='node' && !$vars['is_front']) {
    $vars['YOURTHEME_OR_MODULE_404_on_front']='<DIV>404 ON FRONT</DIV>';
  }
}
```

and then just do a:

```
<?php if (isset($YOURTHEME_OR_MODULE_404_on_front)): ?>
  <?php print $YOURTHEME_OR_MODULE_404_on_front; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

inside your page.tpl.php where you want the information telling your users about the 404.

The only reason I think the above silliness works is because drupal's 404 handler builds the 'node' page manually and displays it, but the theme layer sees what you really typed (eg, myhost.com/foo/bar/baz/bing) and doesn't think it's the front page and sets $is_front accordingly.

I'd assume all of the above would work for a 403 as well, but I haven't figured out a way to pass in which error actually happened, so, you'd have to have this "block" information pretty generic, eg "Oops.  You are in a maze of twisty little passages, all alike..." :)

Comment: I like this method better, although I seem to be stuck at passing variables between preprocess and tpl, despite clearing caches thousand times. `drupal_get_http_header('status')` returns '403 Forbidden', '404 Not Found' (and probably other codes as well)

Answer (score 1):

You can make this with the following configuration and using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.
1. create a page with a custom path ex, "404" and set this page as 404 on configuration -> site information
2. create a rule, if the request page its "404" then 
 2.1 system page redirect
 2.2 system show a message